# How to keep line brakes as it is with Prettier + VS Code Formatting

Tags: visual-studio-code, vuejs3, prettier

I looked for many sources but could not find a way.

I want to make Prettier only format indenting and whitespaces. I don't want it to split multi lines or I don't want it  to merge lines. Just keep lines as they are.

This is how I format my code. I do not split all atributes to new lines and also I do not merge them always. I want that flexibility.

```html
<template>
  <table class="table-a al-l al-m shadow-xs">
    <thead>
      <tr class="g-tit upcase">
        <th class="grp">Lorem}</th>
        <th class="isk">Ipsum</th> 
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
    </tbody> 
  </table>
  
  <!-- CASE-1: @click attribure is breaked into a new line -->
  <Button type="button" :label="CLICK ME" class="p-button" 
          @click="visibleEditForm = true; visibleSaveForm = false;" />

  <!-- CASE-2:  all attribures are on the same line -->
   <Field key="firstName" name="first_name" input="text" v-model="user.firstName" />
</template>
```

The setting I am looking for is something like "keep line brakes".

Is there a solution? Note: I am not restricted to prettier.